# TLS Proxy vs IPsec (gateway-to-host/gateway-to-gateway)

Tags: tls, ipsec

Given some company xyz willing to secure its communication with the external world, what would motivate an IT security architect to pick one solution over the other (i.e. TLS proxy vs IPsec gateway-to-host/gateway-to-gateway)? In other words what would be the pros and cons of either solution?